# How to make a hyperlink in a cell in Excel which can only be clicked, not selected

Tags: excel, hyperlink, ms-office

Please note, **I know how to make hyperlinks in Excel**, that isn't my question.

I have hyperlinks in cells, and they work … mostly. Because to click on a cell is to click on the hyperlink, but also to select the cell.

You have to get the click just right. Sometimes two clicks are needed. Sometimes there's a long pause. Sometimes it doesn't work. The tooltip suggests that a short click will activate the link and holding the mouse down will select the cell without activating it, but in practice this is variable.

I would like to lock the cells for editing, so that a click on that cell is unambiguously a click on the link, just like when I click on a link in a browser. I never have to worry that a click on a link in Chrome is accidentally taken to mean "please edit this content".

When I protect the sheet and lock the cells, which seemed like the logical thing to do, the links stop being clickable.

I could put objects in the cells and make them clickable, but that's a *lot* of work, which I can't do by some kind of Fill Down operation.

Comment: [This site](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/71767-allow-hyperlink-clicks-on-protected-sheet) has a couple creative ideas

Comment: Regarding the last idea in the previous link, you could also set the hyperlinks to re-link themselves after being clicked on so that a purple link is clearly activated https://superuser.com/questions/1276386/reset-a-hyperlink-in-excel